# dropdown appears below content (tried z-index)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to get my drop down (sub-menu) to appear above the content. I have tried z-index and still there is no fix.

Initially the sub-menu starts off with a height of 0 and overflow-hidden (so it isnt shown). I have added JQuery to add a class of open when the parent of the sub menu is clicked. Then I have put a height on. The menu appears fine along with the transition, however the drop down sits below the content and it cannot be clicked.

Can anyone please help?

### CSS

```
.sub-menu{
 height:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.sub-menu li {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 border-top:1px solid;
}

.sub-menu, ul.sub-menu, .sub-menu li, ul.sub-menu li{
 z-index: 5000;
}

li.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
 height: 204px;
}
```

---

### HTML

```
                <div class="col navigation">            
                    <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li class="sub-close"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li class="sub-close"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your element some `position` before the `z-index` will kick into action. I'd suggest also adding this to your `.navigation` divider instead of the `li` elements:

```css
div.navigation {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

You should then give a lower `z-index` to your content just to be on the safe side:

```css
{contentSelector} {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Have a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AX9PV/)

Also, because Im in a good mood, I've tweaked [into a sample horizontal menu](http://jsfiddle.net/AX9PV/1/)

You need to use:

```
ul ul{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Without position set to absolute, the content is effectively being injected before the next list item. You dont necessarily need to use z-index for a vertical menu.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` is not working without `position` you need to set a `position` for your element.

```
.sub-menu, ul.sub-menu, .sub-menu li, ul.sub-menu li{
 position:relative;
 z-index: 5000;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

Comment: Beautiful! Only one issue. Doesn't work in IE7 and i'm developing for IE7 too.

Comment: it needs some change in your html

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the transition, without the `position`,

you need it `relative` to affect the div.

..and I did it in a nice little rhyme for you too :)

Comment: Beautiful! Only one issue. Doesn't work in IE7 and i'm developing for IE7 too.